# How do I remove automatic link Create one from Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Can someone help to remove automatic link called Create One from index page in Active Admin.  Link is shown when there isn't any record created for that model.

here is block of html code that is displayed by default in Active Admin

There are no User yet. [Create one](/admin/users/new)

Answer (score 0):

In `ActiveAdmin` you can specify actions that are available using the `actions` method. To disable the create button both in the top right corner and in the index list you can pass `except` option including the `new` action.

```
ActiveAdmin.register SomeModel do
  actions :all, except: [:new]
end
```

If you only need the `Create One` button in the index list to be disabled then you can monkey patch the `ActiveAdmins` `render_blank_slate` method like this:

```
class ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Index
  protected

  def render_blank_slate
    render_empty_results
  end
end
```

or if you only want this behaviour for a specific model:

```
class ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Index
  protected

  def render_blank_slate
    return render_empty_results if resource_class == User
    super
  end
end
```

Put this code into the `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` file.

Comment: that is not what I am looking for , I need to have New action, just don't want to be available over link on index page   .I want to render blank state for index page or without link.

Answer (score 0):

You will need simply remove file

app/admin/users.rb

It is created by generator.